# CodeIgniter couldn't connect to database

Tags: database, codeigniter, connection

I have a project working perfectly on my local server (xampp) with:

- PHP 5.3.8
- MYSQL 5.5.16
- APACHE 2.2.21

Now, i try to make it work on the web server and CodeIgniter couldn't connect to database.
I try to connect with this code and works ok:

```
$link =  mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
    die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Conectado  satisfactoriamente';
```

but CI says:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

The settings on CI database config file are:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

here, you can see working the basic MySQL connection and the `phpinfo()`

http://guatrache.gov.ar/test.php

and here, you can see the error message from CI:

http://guatrache.gov.ar/index.php

Thanks for your time.

PD: The web server has: PHP 5.3.9, MYSQL 5.1.60

Comment: It looks like you're trying to connect to a database called `database`. Do you actually have a database called `database` to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload the database class, and use active records in your controller. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html